# Obfuscated android library jar file location in android studio 3.1

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-studio-3.0, android-proguard, android-studio-3.1

I have enabled proguard in my android library for code obfuscation. After updating my android studio to **3.1**, I cannot find **obfuscated  .jar file** location of my android library project. Earlier my android library project can be obfuscated and obfuscated .jar can be found at "build/intermediates/bundles/debug/"

Kindly help me to get the obfuscated .jar file location. Or do I have to add any kind of scripts in build.gradle file?

And I have noticed the following:

1. The .jar file location changed from "build/intermediates/bundles/debug/" to "build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/" and ***the .jar file is not obfuscated***
2. .aar file of the library is obfuscated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the **obfuscated jar** file path

> build\intermediates\packaged-classes\debug

If you are not able to find the directory, Clean and rebuild your project.